How to paste all PowerPoint slides to Word?
I need to paste all PowerPoint slides into a table in Word, but each slide must be in a separate block?
Is this possible or must I copy and paste each slide on their own?



This procedure will convert each slide into an image.
You may drag-and-drop all the images into a Word document.

Enter menu File > Save As
Click on More options... and select folder and format as
"JPEG File Interchange Format"
Click Save
Select the option of "All slides".


There's another approach. Directly from PowerPoint, choose File | Export | Create Handouts. That gives you several formatting options; choose the one that suits you.
You end up with a table in word with slide images and a couple other columns. Once it's in Word, you can easily delete any unwanted columns.
I suspect this may only work in the Windows version of PowerPoint.

You are correct, the Mac version of PowerPoint doesn't have that export feature, just a print feature with a handouts option. Yes, you could use that to output to PDF, but then you would have to convert that back to .docx...and so on.
